# Tool/Plug-in to find the CPU & Ram Usage for Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cpu, ram

I have an application which is developed by using Jquery,css,HTML,json & also using some images. The problem with the application is that it runs faster on a browser(Mozila) but is bit slower in the real device(i.e an Oven). I need to find out the CPU & Ram usage when i run the application on the browser in my PC. Is there any free Tool or Plug-in which can show the CPU & Ram usage ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for this. I ran the application in chrome after putting it in Tomcat 7. In chrome we have option in developer tool to find out memory usage & CPU time usage.